# How do I set decimal number format in percentage total format on Cross-Tab report table

Tags: crosstab, crystal-reports-xi

Crystal Reports 11.5 - I have tried to format the % objects in the cross-tab table to show 1 or 2 decimals but it is not saving. As a result the values are all rounded and so the sum of the sub totals does not add to 100% (sometimes only 97%) even the GT shows 100%.
How do I edit the format and save this?[image show table sample with wrong values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZbFr.jpg)